# Creating a time array from a configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angular

Hi all am very new to Javascript and Angular2. Am working on project which needs an array of timing based on a configuration which will be passed from backend. Basically the configuration consists of the following:

```
export const TIMEDATA: any = {
    start_time: "9",
    end_time: "16",
    interval: "30"
}
```

With this configuration, how can I come up with an array something like

```
Array = ["9:00", "9:30", "10:00", ...., "16:00"]
```

Any insights guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to construct an array of TIMEDATA objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a loop to calculate the intervals:

```js
const leftpad = (str, padString, length) => {
    var s = str.toString();
    while (s.length < length)
        s = padString + s;
    return s;
}

let timedata = {
    start_time: "9",
    end_time: "16",
    interval: "30"
}

let start_time = +timedata.start_time * 60;
let end_time = +timedata.end_time * 60;
let interval = +timedata.interval;
let times = [];

for (var i = start_time; i <= end_time; i += interval) {
  let h = Math.floor(i / 60);
  let m = i % 60;
  
  let time = [h, leftpad(m, '0', 2)].join(':');
  times.push(time);
}

console.log(times);
```

Here's a solution that uses lodash. To quickly use lodash in your project, include the script tag in the html page, then `declare _` in the files that use it.

```js
let timedata = {
    start_time: "9",
    end_time: "16",
    interval: "30"
}

let start_time = +timedata.start_time * 60;
let end_time = +timedata.end_time * 60;
let interval = +timedata.interval;

let times = _
  .range(start_time, end_time + interval, interval)
  .map((time) => [
      _.floor(time / 60), 
      _.padStart(time % 60, 2, '0')
    ].join(':'));

console.log(times);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```